Use SQL GROUP BY and CASE WHEN to select specific rows
I have a data set where I want to keep specific value when I GROUP BY id. For example, I have this data:
create table #test1
( 
    id int, 
    category1 varchar(20)
);

insert into #test1 values (1,'AAA');
insert into #test1 values (1,'ZZZ');
insert into #test1 values (1,'YYY');
insert into #test1 values (2,'BBB');
insert into #test1 values (2,'ZZZ');
insert into #test1 values (3,'ZZZ');

So in this example, I want to keep AAA and BBB when multiple rows are present for this id.
The result I want to get is:
id   category1
-------------
 1   AAA
 2   BBB
 3   zzz


You want to filter after grouping? If that's the case you can use HAVING - i.e. select category1, count(id) from #test group by category1 having count(id) > 1

What is the logic behind what you want to keep and what you don't? You need to be able to define that in a way that can be expressed in SQL, and you've not even explained that in English in your post. How specifically do you decide which rows to keep and which ones to ignore?

I'd hazard a guess that you want to keep the "first" value but for old sql salts that is a red flag. SQL data does not imply or guarantee order, as a rule (and sometimes as a technical detail, of some importance). It would be nice to know if you had some primary key here, or a date created, or something that would say what the "first" row for each Id is. Also BTW it is not clear this is a GROUP BY problem at all, yet...(I think you see groups, but that isn't necessarily going to mean you write a query with GROUP BY in it).

For IDs with more than one row you only want to keep AAA and BBB? So, if for an ID there are just XXX and YYY, you'd dismiss this ID completely from your results? Is this correct?

You forgot to tag your request with your DBMS. Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS. It can make a great difference, whether you use MySQL, SQL Server or MS Access for instance.

You don't tell us how the specific values are to be determined. I shall assume that there is a specific logic to it as determined by yourself.
-- 1. Create a table with the rows to be grouped

drop table if exists #RowsToBeGrouped;
go
create table #RowsToBeGrouped(ID int not null primary key, SpecificValue varchar(20) not null);
go
insert into #RowsToBeGrouped(ID, SpecificValue)
select distinct ID, '«empty»' from #test1;
go

-- 2. Update the specific values with the desired values. One UPDATE statement per value.
update rtbg set SpecificValue = 'AAA' from #RowsToBeGrouped rtbg where ID = 1;
update rtbg set SpecificValue = 'BBB' from #RowsToBeGrouped rtbg where ID = 2;
-- ...
update rtbg set SpecificValue = 'ZZZ' from #RowsToBeGrouped rtbg where ID = 999;        -- last value
go

-- 3. Do what needs doing...

-- z. Housekeeping
drop table if exists #RowsToBeGrouped;
go


Use this
select * From (
select  *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by id asc,category1 asc) srno From #test1
) a where srno=1


Please notice that users have had to edit all your answers to format; take some time to learn from that and format your posts initially.

It appears that you are seeking to filter for the "first" category1 value that is encountered in the table. However "first" requires "next" and "last" also and this requires processing by an order. However as soon as you use order by you run the risk of disturbing the wanted results. As noted in a comment by Ken White above ideally there are columns available elsewhere in the table to establish the wanted order (such as a timestamp at insert). In the absence of such column (and assuming you are using SQL Server) there is a "hack" approach to order by (select 1) which "usually" results in the inserted sequence of rows e.g.
select
    *
from (
    select
         id
       , category1
       , row_number() over(partition by id order by (select 1)) as rn
    from #test1
  ) d
where rn = 1




id
category1
rn




1
AAA
1


2
BBB
1


3
ZZZ
1



fiddle
